# Custom Attributes Not Showing Up In Contact Builder

Tags: contact, contactbuilder, attribute

In both Android and iOS we set some custom attributes for marketing to filter on.  In the contact builder's data designer, we are using the system supplied contact key as the primary key and are trying to filter by one of our custom string attributes.  However, it shows we have 0 records even without a filter, just trying to use the contact key as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps are the steps we would advise:

1. Make the Push SDK call again using subscriber key.
2. Log into the MC, in MP and search for the person using the subscriber key
3. Looking at the error, check any date parameters passed.  04/01/2559 19:40:00 is not a valid date.
4. If you can find the subscriber in the MC, then create a filtered list.
5. Let us know what list name you are using if it returns 0 results.

Comment: When looking through the contact linked to the device I am using, no "subscriber key" comes through.  That field is blank in the contact page.